# Convert string to boolean Mule4 Dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have mule4 DW expression which I want to convert into boolean "as boolean" is not working somehow or may be I am just misplacing it.

DW Expression:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
ns ns0 http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/order/2006-10-31
---
[{
    Id: (payload.ns0#order.ns0#"custom-attributes".*ns0#"custom-attribute" filter(item) -> (item.@"attribute-id" == "sscAccountid")) [0],
    Marketing_Opt_in__c: (payload.ns0#order.ns0#"custom-attributes".*ns0#"custom-attribute" filter(item) -> (item.@"attribute-id" == "newsLetterRegistration")) [0] //***This output I want to convert into Boolean***
    
}]
```

XML Tag

```
<custom-attribute attribute-id="newsLetterRegistration">false</custom-attribute>
```

Comment: Hi Pankaj. What does the expresion `(payload.ns0#order.ns0#"custom-attributes".*ns0#"custom-attribute" filter(item) -> (item.@"attribute-id" == "newsLetterRegistration")) [0]`return? Something like "True" or "False". I don't get what needs to be converted to Boolean

Comment: Yes it return true/False, I have updated the question with XML tag I am extracting

Comment: You need to share also the complete XML. Otherwise we can not know what could be the error. Also share what is the error you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[{
Id: (payload.order."custom-attributes".*"custom-attribute" filter(item) -> (item.@"attribute-id" == "sscAccountid"))[0],
Marketing_Opt_in__c: (payload.order."custom-attributes".*"custom-attribute" filter(item) -> (item.@"attribute-id" == "newsLetterRegistration"))[0]
 ~= 'True'  //***This output I want to convert into Boolean***
}]
```

To make it not case sensitive convert both side of comparison to one case, like upper case

```
upper((item.@"attribute-id" == "newsLetterRegistration"))[0])
     ~= 'TRUE'
```

Another way is to use Java Boolean class which does this cast automatically.

```
(item.@"attribute-id" == "newsLetterRegistration"))[0] as Boolean
```

Comment: Thanks Alex,this almost works but somehow always returning 'false' even if I pass <custom-attribute attribute-id="newsLetterRegistration">true</custom-attribute>, can you please check?

Comment: It worked after I removed single quotes from 'True', thankyou very much